# Logarithmic series of numbers from 1 to MAX

Tags: php, math

I'd like to calculate a logarithmic range of numbers from 1 to MAX, with the approximate total count of numbers being TOTAL.

A non-logarithmic example might be:

```
$max = 3600;
$total = 100;

$range = array();
for($i = $total; $i > 0; $i--){
  $range[] = round($max/$i);
}
```

This creates a roughly equally distributed range however.  I'd like the range to have the majority of its numbers in the start, and the less numbers toward the end-- via a logarithmic scale.   The total number of values isn't a strict restriction, just an estimate.

Answer (score 2):

The funny thing about a logarithmic scale is that the elements of your `$range` array (those are the values `x` that you might use to calculate the function values `fct(x)` later) actually have an exponential behaviour, not a logarithmic one. If you look at this [Wikipedia image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aLogLogPlot_of_Line.GIF), you can see that the axis ticks are 10^1, 10^2, 10^3 etc. - this is exponential growth (I'm talking about the axis ticks, not the function itself!).

To generate this, use

```
$max = 3600;
$total = 100;

$range = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
  $range[] = pow($max,$i/($total - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [PDL](http://www.phpmath.com/home) seems to be your best bet here:

```
require_once '../LognormalDistribution.php'; 
require_once 'make_table.php'; 

$mu     = 0.0;
$sigma  = 1.0;

$lognormal = new LognormalDistribution($mu, $sigma);

$Output1 = $lognormal->PDF(.2); 
$Output2 = $lognormal->ICDF(0.95); 
$Output3 = $lognormal->CDF(.50);
```

Hope that helps...